# How to make Laravel Eloquent Query more dynamic?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Based on some inputs, whether they are not null, I want to perform a Eloquent Query. I want to add the following attributes to query if they are not null.

How to make this query work?

```
 $property = Property::
        where('published','=','1');

        if(!empty($searchInput)){
            $property+=$property
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', $percentageSearch)
            ->orWhere('village', 'like', $percentageSearch)
            ->orWhere('address', 'like', $percentageSearch)
            ->orWhere('reference_point', 'like', $percentageSearch)
            ->orWhere('price', 'like', $percentageSearch);
        }

        if(!empty($typeInput)){

            $property+=$property
            ->orWhere('type', '=', $typeInput);
        }

        if(!empty($categoryInput)){
            $property+=$property
            ->orWhere('category_id', '=', $categoryInput);
        }
        $prop=$property->get();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... remove all the `+` from this, you are not adding numbers or merging arrays here ... besides that you probably need to do grouping of wheres here

Comment: btw what would be "more dynamic" than this for you? not sure what you are thinking

Comment: [This video](https://laracasts.com/series/eloquent-techniques/episodes/4) might be of use.

Answer (score 1):

Use a local scope and conditional queries.

```
$property = Property::where('published_at', 1)->search($searchInput, $typeInput, $categoryInput)->get();
```

```
// Property Model
public function scopeSearch($builder, $search, $type, $category)
{
    return $builder->where(function ($query) use ($search, $type, $category) {
        $query->when($search, function ($property, $search) {
                  $property->orWhere('name', 'like', $search)
                           ->orWhere('village', 'like', $search)
                           ->orWhere('address', 'like', $search)
                           ->orWhere('reference_point', 'like', $search)
                           ->orWhere('price', 'like', $search);
              })
              ->when($type, function ($property, $type) {
                  $property->orWhere('type', '=', $type);
              })
              ->when($category, function ($property, $category) {
                  $property->orWhere('category_id', '=', $category);
              });
    });
}
```

- [Logical Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping)
- [Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses)
- [Local Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes)

Comment: the second argument passed to the callback for `when` is the value you are testing, so you can add that to the argument list instead of needing a `use`, fyi

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that. Thanks for the tip @lagbox. Since I mostly use shorthand closures on my projects I'm not used to caring about the extra params.